# how to make start_urls in scrapy pick up url generated by another python function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my code to get url of the items from ebay i.e. link3:

```
def url_soup(url):

    source=(urllib2.urlopen(url)).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source)
    link=soup.select('a.ListItemLink')
    for links in link:
        link3=('http://www.ebay.com/'+'%s') % (links['href'])


Dept={"All Departments":"0","Apparel":"5438","Auto":"91083","Baby":"5427","Beauty":"1085666",
"Books":"3920","Electronics":"3944","Gifts":"1094765","Grocery":"976759","Health":"976760",
"Home":"4044","Home Improvement":"1072864","Jwelery":"3891","Movies":"4096","Music":"4104",
"Party":"2637","Patio":"5428","Pets":"5440","Pharmacy":"5431","Photo Center":"5426",
"Sports":"4125","Toys":"4171","Video Games":"2636"}

def gen_url(keyword,domain):

     if domain in Dept.keys():
        main_url=('http://www.ebay.com/search/search-ng.do?search_query='+'%s'+'&ic=16_0&Find=Find&search_constraint='+'%s') % (keyword,Dept.get(domain))
     url_soup(main_url)

gen_url('Bags','Apparel')
```

Now i want my spider to pick `start_urls` as `link3` everytime.
P.s. i'm new to scrapy!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method to dynamically define urls for the spider to start with.

For example, you should have something like this:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "my_spider"
    domains = ['Auto']
    departments = {"All Departments": "0", "Apparel": "5438", "Auto": "91083", "Baby": "5427", "Beauty": "1085666",
                   "Books": "3920", "Electronics": "3944", "Gifts": "1094765", "Grocery": "976759", "Health": "976760",
                   "Home": "4044", "Home Improvement": "1072864", "Jwelery": "3891", "Movies": "4096", "Music": "4104",
                   "Party": "2637", "Patio": "5428", "Pets": "5440", "Pharmacy": "5431", "Photo Center": "5426",
                   "Sports": "4125", "Toys": "4171", "Video Games": "2636"}
    keyword = 'Auto'

    allowed_domains = ['ebay.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for domain in self.domains:
            if domain in self.departments:
                url = 'http://www.ebay.com/search/search-ng.do?search_query=%s&ic=16_0&Find=Find&search_constraint=%s' % (self.keyword, self.departments.get(domain))
                print "YIELDING"
                yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        print "IN PARSE"
        sel = Selector(response)
        links = sel.select('//a[@class="ListItemLink"]/@href')
        for link in links:
            href = link.extract()[0]
            yield Request('http://www.ebay.com/' + href, self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        # do your actual crawling here
        print "IN PARSE DATA"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Now what happened is while requesting the url to parse_data it's not working. Meanwhile giving me the url as output. Means crawling is not happening correctly or it's not getting the response for those particular urls.

Comment: @user3488659 I've updated the code - showing what I'm using right now. There is at least one problem: ebay shows 404 on a search page in `start_requests`: `http://www.ebay.com/search/search-ng.do...`. Are you sure this is the correct search url you need?

Comment: ohh,i'm sorry for that.i just registered today so SO wasn't allowing me to paste more than two links and i changed them to example.com but still not able to proceed so tried with ebay and it was done. I'm really sorry for that. It's actually walmart. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @user3488659 ok, then run my code with "walmart" and see what is printed on the console.

Comment: i tried your code and it was giving this warning:
 ScrapyDeprecationWarning: scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated, instantiate scrapy.selector.Selector instead.
  hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
/home/vivek/mywork/walmart_sample/walmart_sample/spiders/test.py:27: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead. What does this warning for exactly?
  links = hxs.select('//a[@class="ListItemLink"]/@href')
I changed the selector to HtmlXPathSelector as well but still not crawling ahead.Should i use CrawlSpider instead???

Comment: @user3488659 don't worry too much about `DeprecationWarning`s - it is not related to the problem. You are also ok with `BaseSpider`. Besides warning what print statements worked - which of them do you see on the console?

Comment: i think def parse may be causing problem as by default it takes parse function and may be overriding it.I'll have a check on that as well.

Comment: @user3488659 then, links are not found probably, check the xpath used in `parse()`.

Comment: Yeah,i was missing one thing in the xpath.Your help is quite appreciated but from where i have started i reached there itself.#MyBAD!!!
actually same crawling i tried in different way too but now in your code also it's doing same thing printing links of PARSE function not the details inside those. Any idea?

Comment: thanks buddy!! Atlast i'm able to scrap something. Now to call recursively i'll try and may be if struck somewhere will trouble you soon.Hope i'll not!! Thanks a lot once again!! :)

Comment: @user3488659 you are welcome, happy web-scraping! :)